# Java - Most efficient structure for quick retrieval

Tags: java, string, data-structures

I have a very simple problem: I need to check if a large (150k) list of strings contains a certain string. Order does not matter, and I only need to check if the list contains a string. What is the most efficient data structure to use?

Comment: A list is a data structure. Are you instead asking what is the most efficient approach to using a list data structure to find a matching string?

Comment: If you have list already ---> Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);

Comment: I would consider a Trie - Apache commons has a compressed Trie that performs well PatriciaTrie<E>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at set (Hashset, enumset) and hash (HashMap,linkedhash...,idnetityhash..) based implementations, they have a speed complexity of O(1) for the contains() method.

[this](http://infotechgems.blogspot.ca/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html) is a great link to use

Answer (score 1):

You want some structure that uses a hash function to insert, retrieve and delete elements. They usually have a theoretical O(1) complexity in those operations.

If all the strings are different, then you can use a `HashSet`. If you can have repeated elements, then you can use a `HashMap` that maps a `String` to an `Integer` that has how many of that elements you have.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a hashmap, it will give you O(1) complexity, just go ahead and store both the key and value pairs as hm.put(string,string); where hm is your hashmap.